What does this syntax mean in CSS?
What does this syntax mean?
Syntax: [ <display-outside> || <display-inside> ] | <display-listitem> | <display-internal> | <display-box> | <display-legacy>

How to understand this?
Are there any official w3 docs referring to this?

Where did you get this from? Is there any more context? Like the property this syntax applies to? I guess it's display? Either way a quick google (err, DuckDuckGo even) gives me a detailed explanation on MDN for one of them: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display-outside and I haven't even tried the others. That page even links to the specification.

Take à look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display . It tells you what it means and which display value it refers to

@somethinghere I got this on VS Code, when I hover over a CSS declaration, this text pops up. However, there aren't any links explaining this syntax inside the vs code. Different declarations would reveals varying syntax formats. For example, hovering over background-color displays Syntax: [, ]* 

In that case you might want to look for and install the MDN extension, which will links your hovers to the actual documentation on MDN, which will be rather useful if you so wish!

The syntax is formally specified in the CSS Values and Units Module, in the section Value Definition Syntax.

The "|" symbol typically denotes a choice between options, so you can choose one option from each of these categories to define the display behavior of an element.
As for official documentation, the syntax you provided correspond to CSS    'display' property. It is a value definition "syntax" that is used to define the set of valid values for CSS properties. You can refer to the CSS Display Module Level 3 specification for detailed information on the display property and its possible values.
__
Answer edited, thanks @temani-afif for contributing to the problem.

it's actually the syntax of the display value: https://w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#the-display-properties

No, it's not. The values presented in angle brackets represent a conceptual breakdown, you can't use something like "display: " in valid CSS syntax. And btw our links lead to the same material...

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values/#value-defs --> The value definition syntax described here is used to define the set of valid values for CSS properties. So it's the "syntax" of the display property. It's not my opinion, it's defined that way in the Spec.

Now I see the point, thank you for the clarification
